# Notifications in a foreground service

Tags: android

I have several questions to notifications and foreground tasks. First, this is my Service:

```
public class NFCUploadService extends Service implements MeasureDataPostCallback {
    private static final int IMAGE_SEND_NFC_SERVICE_ID = 100;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ForegroundServiceTags.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION.getValue())) {
            String email = intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_EMAIL);
            String password = intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_PASSWORD);
            String year = intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_YEAR);
            String month = intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_MONTH);
            String day = intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_DATE);
            String hour = intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_HOUR);
            String minute = intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_MINUTE);
            String value = intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_VALUE);
            String mealTime = intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_MEALTIME);
            String mood = intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_MOOD);
            File imageFile = null;

            if(intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_FILE_PATH) != null) {
                imageFile = new File(intent.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_FILE_PATH));
            }

            MeasureDataPostTask task = new MeasureDataPostTask(email, password, year, month, day, hour, minute, value, mealTime, mood, imageFile);
            task.setCallback(this);
            task.execute(this);

            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
            builder.setContentTitle("Progress");
            builder.setContentText("Sending Data...");
            builder.setTicker("Notification!");
            builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            builder.setOngoing(true);
            Notification notification = builder.build();

            this.startForeground(IMAGE_SEND_NFC_SERVICE_ID, notification);
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasureDataPostCompleted(StatusMeasureDataPost status, MeasureDataPostPOJO measureDataPostPojo) {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Progress");
        builder.setTicker("Notification!");
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setOngoing(true);

        switch(status) {
        case ERROR_CONNECTION_FAILED:
            builder.setContentText("Connection Failed");
            break;
        case ERROR_DB_CONNECTION_FAILED:
            builder.setContentText("DB Connection Failed");
            break;
        case ERROR_IO_EXCEPTION:
            builder.setContentText("IO Exception");
            break;
        case ERROR_JSON_EXCEPTION:
            builder.setContentText("JSON Exception");
            break;
        case ERROR_MEASUREDATA_ALREADY_EXISTS:
            builder.setContentText("Data already exists");
            break;
        case ERROR_PROTOCOL_EXCEPTION:
            builder.setContentText("Protocol Exception");
            break;
        case ERROR_WRONG_PARAMETERS:
            builder.setContentText("Wrong Parameters");
            break;
        case MEASUREDATA_TRANSFER_SUCCESSFUL:
            builder.setContentText("Transfer complete");
            break;
        }

        Notification notification = builder.build();

        this.startForeground(IMAGE_SEND_NFC_SERVICE_ID, notification);
    }
}
```

As long as my AsyncTask (MeasureDataPostTask) is not finished I want my service to be unkillable. That means I don't want the user to be able to swipe away the notification in the notification tab of android devices.

After the AsyncTask finishes (that's when `onMeasureDataPostCompleted` is called) I want my notification to change, I want to print out a result message and make the notification killable. The user should be able to swipe away the notification after the AsyncTask finished but not while it's running. How can I achieve that?

Later I also want to add a mechanism which repeats the AsyncTask every 5 minutes when the AsyncTask failed caused by a missing internet connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are suppose to call `startForeground()` from `onStartCommand()`.

To repeat the `AsyncTask`, you should set an Alarm which resends your `STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION` intent.